# Error response from daemon: network mongo-network not found

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-network

```bash
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-185:~$ docker run -p 27017:27017 -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME:admin -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD:password --name mongodb-one --net mongo-network -d mongo

2beb800894fbbd3d2e128de667ba155cdd4065c4d20331ecffa510a06121cbb8
docker: Error response from daemon: network mongo-network not found.
```

I've tried everything, as far I know! Is there anything missing in the above command?

Answer (score 1):

you need to check is mongo-network available using

```bash
docker network ls
```

If not then create the mongo-network with the create sub-command. The Error says it does not exist so this is what required.

```
docker network create mongo-network
```

Hope this will solves your error.